# JAX WS using CXF and Webphere 8.5 (org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler incompatible with org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy)

Tags: java, websphere, cxf, apache-axis

I had an application running in Webphere 6 and JDK 1.6. Now I'm trying to migrate it to Whephere Application Server 8.5. I get a problem related to libraries used to consume SOAP Services (Im using CXF). The problem is that Webphere in this version, has its own libraries to do this (AXIS2). I followed IBM recomendations
'Using a third-party JAX-WS web services engine' 
-https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_thirdparty.html- 
**IT DOESN'T WORK FOR ME**

However, I found that someone solved it removing a file from the META-INF AXIS2 library in Websphere. (javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider) **=====IT WORKED=====** But now I'm having other derived problems

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

org/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchemaCollection.read(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/ws/commons/schema/XmlSchema; 
(loaded from file:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/plugins/**org.apache.axis2.jar** by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader@41aaaf6e) 
called from class org.apache.cxf.common.xmlschema.SchemaCollection (
loaded 
from file:/usr/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppServer01/installedApps/CLDC462Cell01/MyApp.ear/myapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/**cxf-core-3.1.5.jar** 
by 
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@5344aede

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: You can also flag this post for moderator attention if you want it disassociated from your account.

Answer (score 1):

Your app is picking up some Apache classes from the WebSphere libraries rather than from your application, and the version in WebSphere is incompatible with the app's version of CXF.  This means that you're going to need to add a jar containing an appropriate version of `org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection` to your application.  I presume that you're running with PARENT_LAST delegation in your web module already, given that you're using your own web services implementation, but if not, that will be necessary as well.

Comment: Back in the WAS6 days, WebSphere did not have jax-ws at all.  If your app is a jax-ws app, you might be able to just delete those cxf jars and let WebSphere supply the jax-ws implementation.